# Keep user logged in Fireauth

Tags: java, android, firebase

So I have this problem that my user gets `logged out when the app is closed`, not minimized. Is there a way to stop this from happening, so the user dosen't have to login every time he/she closes the app? I disabled `setIsSmartLockEnabled`, because it's a bit anoying that the user automatically gets signed in, because lets say another user need to login to the app, then the problem appears.

Here is some code:

```java
List<AuthUI.IdpConfig> providers = Arrays.asList(
        new AuthUI.IdpConfig.EmailBuilder().build(),
        new AuthUI.IdpConfig.FacebookBuilder().build());
startActivityForResult(AuthUI.getInstance().createSignInIntentBuilder().setLogo(R.drawable.menolonely).setAvailableProviders(providers)
        .setIsSmartLockEnabled(false).build(), RC_SIGN_IN);


@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
            if (user != null) {

            //user.... stuff here

            } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "Error on login");
            finish();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where in your code are you calling `signOut()`?

Comment: in my menu. But i think my problem is that i always build the login screen even if the user is logged in. so i have to make that different